# Fast double-valued priority queue implementation in Java

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, priority-queue, stanford-nlp

I am looking for an implementation of a priority queue that uses constant `double` values as priorities for the key. I believe that this, if implemented properly, can be faster than the default `PriorityQueue` implementation with a flexible comparator. A decreaseKey operation (=decreasing the priority of an element already in the queue) is not necessary.

I have found an [implementation from the NLP group in Stanford](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/edu/stanford/nlp/stanford-corenlp/1.3.0/stanford-corenlp-1.3.0-javadoc.jar!/javadoc/edu/stanford/nlp/util/PriorityQueue.html), but they claim that it's twice as *slow* as the original implementation. Is there a PQ implementation out there that can outperform the default `PriorityQueue` for our use case?

Comment: Why not whip up your own?  It's not really that difficult.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Code reuse? Relying on other people's result, especially w.r.t. runtime tests and fine-tuning? Save several hours of implementation and testing time? Just some reasons that come to my mind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up implementing our own heap structure. A d-ary heap with an optimized `remove()` operation turned out to perform reasonably well, especially on a loaded shared-memory machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Sedgewick-Wayne code at

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/MaxPQ.java.html

but replace the generic Key type with double and remove the Comparable/Comparator code.

Answer (score 0):

The slower speed of the Stanford NLP version you cite is because it does support decreaseKey(). As mentioned in its Javadoc, you can try this class, which doesn't support decreaseKey():

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/edu/stanford/nlp/stanford-corenlp/1.3.0/stanford-corenlp-1.3.0-javadoc.jar!/javadoc/edu/stanford/nlp/util/FixedPrioritiesPriorityQueue.html